# Why is Ubuntu dirmngr process consuming 100% of cpu?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, ubuntu-18.04

[Cross posting from AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129531/ubuntu-dirmngr-process-is-consuming-100-of-my-cpu):

I couldn't find this asked anywhere else, so apologies if it has already been. I've discovered a recent problem where dirmngr consumes 100% of my CPU for hours without stopping. I can't kill the process without shutting the machine down. It seems to be associated with JetBrains products (I usually hear my fan kicking in during Indexing), but I'm not sure about that. Does anyone have an idea what might be happening?

[image: dirmngr consumes 100% CPU]

OS details:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Release: 18.04

Codename: bionic

Answer (score 2):

I have a very similar problem on openSUSE, and Googling I have found reports from Arch and Mint as well. I think this is not specific to Ubuntu.

I could see that dirmngr was repeatedly accessing my GPG keys in ~/.ssh.

It is not a perfect solution, but I added "seahorse" and the necessary packages to use the GNOME keyring on my Xfce machine. I have configured the GNOME keyring to store my GPG passphrase in my login keyring and unlock it when I log in.

Now I can access devices using my stored GPG keys (such as Github) without entering my passphrase.

Dirmngr is still running but now it uses far less CPU and my machine is running quicker.

I cannot imagine it is connected, but: the problem first appeared for me when I added a 2nd graphics card to supplement my nVidia Quadro K620 (GM107GL GPU). I now also have a GeForce GT 220 (GT216 GPU) with a 3rd screen attached for a triple-head setup using Nouveau drivers.